is it possible to create AWS health check alarms based on route 53 health check outside us-east-1 region?
I am trying to create Route 53 health check and create metric and alarm in eu-west-1, and ideally I want the health check metrics and alarm to be in eu-west-1, and it is not clear in AWS doc if it is possible to have native Route 53 health check alarm outside us-east-1 region. so the question is; is it possible to create AWS health check alarms based on route 53 health check outside us-east-1 region?
